# CW structure on Unitary Group

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, reference-request

I computed  the CW structure on U(n) using morse theory.I want to verify my answer.So I was wondering if someone here can supply the answer as I can't find any source by googling.Also I want to know if there is any reference for this.

Comment: See Theorem (2.2) in http://arxiv.org/abs/dg-ga/9506004

Comment: I think the cell structure is worked out in Milnor and Stasheff's Characteristic classes and/or Steenrod's Intro to Fibre Bundles.


Comment: This can be found in the book "Cohomology Operations" by Steenrod and Epstein, Chapter 4, where they also do the parallel cases of orthogonal and symplectic groups, as well as the generalizations to Stiefel manifolds.  For the original source in the unitary case they cite the paper of I. Yokota, "On the cellular decompositions of unitary groups", J. Inst. Polytech., Osaka City Univ. 7 (1956), 39-49.  

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this question. Surely different Morse functions lead to different CW structures?

Comment: Mark: I think usually one is interested in decompositions with the minimal number of cells. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simply-connected compact Lie group $G$ has the same rational homotopy type (and rational cohomology ring) of as a product of odd-dimensional spheres $S^{2m_1+1}\times\cdots\times S^{2m_r+1}$ where the $m_i$ are 
invariants called *exponents* and $r$ is the rank of $G$. (The exponents are related to 
many algebraic invariants of $G$).

In your case $U(n)$ is diffeomorphic to $S^1 \times SU(n)$ and the exponents
of $SU(n)$ are $1,\ldots, n-1$. For instance, in case $n=3$, $SU(3)$ has
exponents $1$, $2$ and $U(3)\sim S^1 \times S^3 \times S^5$ has a cell decomposition with one cell in each dimension $0$, $1$, $3$, $4$, $5$, $6$, $8$, $9$.

Classical references are A. Borel http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1955-61-05/S0002-9904-1955-09936-1/home.html and H. Samelson
http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1952-58-01/S0002-9904-1952-09544-6/home.html.

*Edit:* There is the maybe easier following argument. In general, for a 
(locally trivial) fiber bundle $\pi:E\to B$ with typical fiber $F$, where
$B$ and $F$ are CW-complexes, a cell decomposition for the total space $E$ is the same
as that of the direct product $B\times F$, since each cell $c$ of $B$ is contractible
and thus the bundle above it is trivial: $\pi^{-1}(c)\cong c\times F$.

Now consider the (principal) fiber bundle
$SU(n-1)\to SU(n)\to S^{2n-1}$ for $n\geq2$ and apply induction.

*Edit 2:* The minimal number of cells in a CW-decomposition equals the sum of the Betti numbers over $\mathbf Z_2$ (or any field), by the Morse inequalities. We need only to know that $G$ and $S^{2m_1+1}\times\cdots\times S^{2m_r+1}$ have the same $\mathbf Z_2$-Betti numbers, so the minimal number of cells in this case is $2^r$, where $r$ is the rank of $G$.

Comment: Could you please give some references?

Comment: Your claim "$G$ has the same homotopy type as a product of odd-dimensional spheres" is only true *rationally*, isn't it?

Comment: Christian: I've edited my post, thanks. 

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, a rationall cell decomposition need not come from an honest CW decomposition.